# Extracting group memberships

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group, activedirectorymembership

I am have a list of active directory computers on a file, and I would like to see for each of one them, what groups they belong to.
It is very long when you have 200-300 to do manually, but I think with a script it takes a few seconds.
I would really appreciate your help. I have tried the search before asking for help but I couldn't find what I want :(

Comment: No one has answered because it seems you are looking for someone to write this for you. You can get better help if you show what you have attempted and explain why it isn't working for you yet.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: you're really looking for computers and not the users who use those computers. Putting computers in groups is far less common.

If the file of computers is just a flat notepad file, 1 system per line.

This will get you the CN's of all the groups involved.

```
$AllSystems = Get-Content ".\CompList.txt" 
foreach($OneSystem in $AllSystems)
{
    write-host $OneSystem -foreground yellow
    Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -eq $OneSystem} -properties * | select -ExpandProperty Memberof
}
```

Your output will be the machine name (in yellow) followed by a list of all the groups that machine is in.

If your wanting the more friendly name of the group, try this:

```
$AllSystems = Get-Content ".\CompList.txt" 
foreach($OneSystem in $AllSystems)
{
    write-host $OneSystem -foreground yellow
    Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -eq $OneSystem} -properties * | select -ExpandProperty Memberof| %{get-adgroup -identity $_} | select name
}
```